# How can I make my function use two helper functions to return the desired output?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

So I'm trying to create a function def mealcal(data, recipes, menu ) that takes in three strings like

```
menu = ["T-Bone", "T-Bone", "Green Salad1"]
recipes = ["Pork Stew:Cabbage*5,Carrot*1,Fatty Pork*10",
           "Green Salad1:Cabbage*10,Carrot*2,Pineapple*5",
           "T-Bone:Carrot*2,Steak Meat*1"]
data = ["Cabbage:4,2,0", "Carrot:9,1,5", "Fatty Pork:431,1,5",
        "Pineapple:7,1,0", "Steak Meat:5,20,10", "Rabbit Meat:7,2,20"]
```

and returns

```
[22295, 690, 405]
```

In order to do this I've created multiple helper functions to get to the result, and here is the code..

```
def totalcal(data):
    calorie_dict = {}
    for el in data:
      food, values = el.split(':')
      a, b, c = values.split(',')
      calories = (int(a) * 5) + (int(b) * 5) + (int(c) * 9)
      calorie_dict[food] = calories
    return calorie_dict
def rdict(recipes):
    recipes_splitted = {}
    for r in recipes:
        recipe_name, parts = r.split(":")
        recipe_parts = {}
        for part in parts.split(','):
            product, number = part.split('*')
            recipe_parts[product] = int(number)
        recipes_splitted[recipe_name] = recipe_parts
    return recipes_splitted
def extract(recipes, menu):
    data = rdict(menu)
    result = []
    for r in recipes:
        tmp = []
        for key in data[r]:
            tmp.append(f"{key}:{data[r][key]}")
        final_string = ""
        for i in range(len(tmp)):
            if i < len(tmp) - 1:
                final_string += tmp[i] + ", "
            else:
                final_string += tmp[i]
        result.append(final_string)
    return result
def recipecal(recipes, data):
    calories_list = []
    for recipe_name in rdict(recipes):
        recipe_parts = rdict(recipes)[recipe_name]
        calories = 0
        for product in recipe_parts:
            number = recipe_parts[product]
            calories += number * totalcal(data)[product]
        calories_list.append(calories)
    return calories_list
print(extract(['T-Bone', 'Green Salad1','T-Bone'],["Pork Stew:Cabbage*5,Carrot*1,Fatty Pork*10",
"Green Salad1:Cabbage*10,Carrot*2,Pineapple*5",
"T-Bone:Carrot*2,Steak Meat*1"]))
def mealcal(menu, recipes, data):
    x = extract(recipes,menu)
    return recipecal(x,data)
```

So now, for `mealcal(menu, recipes, data)` to work, I must put the inputs `recipes` and `menu` into my helper function `extract` since the function extract will return the output like this

```
['Carrot:2, Steak Meat:1', 'Cabbage:10, Carrot:2, Pineapple:5', 'Carrot:2, Steak Meat:1']
```

I must then use this output of `extract(recipes,menu)` to put into the recipes portion of `recipecal(recipes,data)`

**Data is a seperate string that will be inputted at the start and it will look like this**

```
data = ["Cabbage:4,2,0", "Carrot:9,1,5", "Fatty Pork:431,1,5",
"Pineapple:7,1,0", "Steak Meat:5,20,10", "Rabbit Meat:7,2,20"]
```

Furthermore, when the two inputs are put into recipecal(recipes,data), the function will return the numbers

```
[22295, 690, 405]
```

So now my issue is how can I program `mealcal(menu, recipes, data)` to put `recipes` and `menu` into `extract(recipes, menu)` and then take the output of `extract(recipes, menu)` and input it into the `recipe` portion of `totalcal(recipes,data)` and then return the output correctly??

**Please use the simplest method of code possible. I'm not very strong in programming and I would like to understand the codes that I write. Thank you:)**

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. One function should return results and you should use this result as value in next funtion  - `result1 = function1() ; result2 = function2(result1, other values)` OR shorter `result2 = function2(function1(), other values)`

Comment: I think you made it too complex - inside `recipecal()` you runs `rdict(recipes)` in `for recipe_name in rdict(recipes)` and later again in `recipe_parts = rdict(recipes)[recipe_name]` but you could run it only once and assing to variable. OR even better you could could run it before `recipecal()` and send result to `recipecal()`

Comment: Thank you for ur response, can u explain in code terms what u mean btw?? It would help a lot :)

Comment: I means that you mess in code - you repeate the same function many times but you should run it only once, get result and later use this result in next functions - but you always send original data and it has to run the same function many times.

Comment: BTW: you run `rdict(menu)` but `rdict` was created to split `recipes` which has `:` in string but `menu` doesn't have `:` - and this rasise error.

Comment: ahh thank you for pointing my mistake, so where should I edit my code??

Comment: problem `rdict(menu) is in `extract()` in line `data = rdict(menu)` - it should be `data = menu`. But at this mement I fount that you don't need function `extract` at all. You can remove `x = extract(recipes,menu)`  from `mealcal()` and use `return recipecal(recipes,data)` instread of `return recipecal(x,data)`. To say something I have to put `print()` in many places to see what this code is really doing. You could also use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here working code.

This part was correct

```
    x = extract(recipes,menu)
    return recipecal(x,data)
```

But there was few mistakes inside `extract()` which made problem.

It was using `:` instead of `*` - so it was creating `product:number` instead of `product*number`,

It didn't add `name:` before `product1*number1,product1*number1`

Rest is rather the same.

```
def rdict(recipes):
    recipes_splitted = {}
    for r in recipes:
        recipe_name, parts = r.split(":")
        recipe_parts = {}
        for part in parts.split(','):
            product, number = part.split('*')
            recipe_parts[product] = int(number)
        recipes_splitted[recipe_name] = recipe_parts
    return recipes_splitted

def totalcal(data):
    calorie_dict = {}
    for el in data:
        food, values = el.split(':')
        a, b, c = values.split(',')
        calories = (int(a) * 5) + (int(b) * 5) + (int(c) * 9)
        calorie_dict[food] = calories
    return calorie_dict

def extract(recipes, menu):
    recipes = rdict(recipes)
    result = []
    for r in menu:
        tmp = []
        for key in recipes[r]:
            tmp.append(f"{key}*{recipes[r][key]}")  
        final_string = f"{r}:"
        for i in range(len(tmp)):
            if i < len(tmp) - 1:
                final_string += tmp[i] + ","
            else:
                final_string += tmp[i]
        result.append(final_string)
    return result

def recipecal(recipes, data):
    calories_list = []
    for recipe_name in rdict(recipes):
        recipe_parts = rdict(recipes)[recipe_name]
        calories = 0
        for product in recipe_parts:
            number = recipe_parts[product]
            calories += number * totalcal(data)[product]
        calories_list.append(calories)
    return calories_list

def mealcal(menu, recipes, data):
    recipes = extract(recipes, menu)
    return recipecal(recipes, data)
    # OR
    #return recipecal(extract(recipes, menu), data)

# --- main ---

data = [
    "Cabbage:4,2,0",
    "Carrot:9,1,5",
    "Fatty Pork:431,1,5",
    "Pineapple:7,1,0",
    "Steak Meat:5,20,10",
    "Rabbit Meat:7,2,20"
] 

recipes = [
    "Pork Stew:Cabbage*5,Carrot*1,Fatty Pork*10",
    "Green Salad1:Cabbage*10,Carrot*2,Pineapple*5",
    "T-Bone:Carrot*2,Steak Meat*1"
]

#menu = ['T-Bone',    'Green Salad1', 'T-Bone']
menu = ['Pork Stew', 'Green Salad1', 'T-Bone']

result = mealcal(menu, recipes, data)

print(result)
```

---

```
menu = ['T-Bone',    'Green Salad1', 'T-Bone']
#menu = ['Pork Stew', 'Green Salad1', 'T-Bone']

result = []

for single_product in menu: 
    #print(single_product)  

    # `menu` was a list `[string, string, string]
    # `single_product` is a `string` but `mealcal` needs list `[string]`
    single_result = mealcal( [single_product] , recipes, data)

    #print(single_result)

    result = result + single_result   # [a] + [b] gives [a, b]
    
print(result)
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much for ur explaination and code!. btw just wondering, how can I make it work if I want like two inputs... so like when in menu, when I input ['T-Bone","Green Salad1","T-bone"], the answer for T-Bone only appears once like [405, 690].... What should I change so that the output returns the same number of times oas the number of inputs.. ,for instance if the input is   ['T-Bone","Green Salad1","T-bone"], the output would be [405, 690, 405] instead of just  [405, 690]??

Comment: This is for mealcal(menu, recipes, data) btw

Comment: I saw this problem. Problem is that code uses dictionary to keep some data - and dictionary can't keep the same key two times. The only idea: use `for`-loop to run code three times for three lists `['T-Bone"], [ Green Salad1"], ["T-bone"]` and later put all three results in one list.

Comment: I added `for`-loop which resolve it

Comment: can I put that for loop under the function mealcal?? Because I want it to print directly

Comment: maybe try it and you will see if it will work.

Comment: I tried doing it but it doesn't work since result is not defined for some reason. Is there a different way to put that for loop under mealcal??

Comment: if `result` is not defined then define it. In my code I have `result = []` for some reason. If you want to use `for`-loop inside function then you have to also use `result = []` inside function. And if you want to use print(result)` then you have to assign `result = mealcal(...)` like in old version without `for`-loop.